# Owl carousel custom navigation

Tags: html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel,

The navigation on it looks like this:

[image]

I want to make only two navigation buttons that look like this:

[image]

I tried to do addinf this line :

```
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["<img src='resources/img/arrow-left.png'>","<img src='resources/img/arrow-right.png'>"]
});
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way that I can delete one of the dots and make the other two apear like in the picture.

Comment: The dots work different than your proposed navigation system. Yours would rotate the images left or right whereas the owl carousel's default navigation links to a specific image. Unless you only have two images you'll have to change the way the owl carousel's navigation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{   
    jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        dots:false,
        nav:true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution is just remove `*= require owl.theme` this css
and keep only `navigation: true`

```
 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            navigation: true
 });
```